# Seg Fault when using malloc for an array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to implement a cache struct with pointers that point to "lower-level" set structs; It's supposed to simulate a cache. When I try to malloc the cache struct in the initCache function I get a seg fault. I've read other posts and I'm pretty sure it's not the syntax, but I'm new to C so I could be using the pointers wrong. I get a warning that L1cache may be uninitialized and I've also checked posts related to that but with no luck, trying what worked for others.

TO be clear the **sets in the cache definition is supposed to be an array of pointers where each pointer in the array points to a struct

The cache struct is defined as:

```
/* Struct representing the cache */
struct cache{
    set **sets; /* Array of set pointers */
};
```

initCache is called in main as such:

```
cache* L1cache;
initCache(L1cache, nSets, setSize);
```

The code for initCache is:

```
void initCache(cache* c, int nSets, int setSize){
    int i;

    c->sets=malloc(nSets*sizeof(set*)); /* SEG FAULT HERE malloc space for array of pointers to each set       */

    for(i = 0; i < nSets; i++){
        c->sets[i]=malloc(sizeof(set)); /* malloc space for each set */
    initSet(c->sets[i],setSize);
}

    return;     
}
```

Comment: `cache* L1cache` not initialized to point to a valid memory address of a **properly allocated** `cache` instance, so it is most likely pointing to an invalid memory address, or to a valid one but not of a **properly allocated** `cache` instance (in short, the value of this variable is "junk").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `L1cache`:

```
cache *L1cache = malloc(sizeof (cache));
```

Or you could just declare it as an ordinary variable:

```
char L1cache;
initCache(&L1cache, nSets, setSize);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked great, I'm new to C and there are a lot of things that are hard to figure out without good help